# Laravel - Create list of most common occurance from two columns

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have this table in a database:

```
| PaintId | Foreground | Background |
|---------|------------|------------|
| 1       | Red        | Cyan       |
| 2       | Cyan       | Blue       |
| 3       | Red        | Pink       |
| 4       | Red        | Pink       |
| 5       | Red        | Blue       |
| 6       | Green      | Blue       |
| 7       | Yellow     | Orange     |
| 8       | Pink       | Red        |
```

How would I use Laravel to create a list of the most common occurance in Foreground and Background database columns no matter if the either color is in background or foreground.

With this calculation, the most common occurance would be "Red and Pink" with a total of 3 times.

Comment: okay so you want common data of both coloumn right?

Comment: @VikasKatariya Yes. A list of most common occurances and their count from either column (foreground/background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure this would work by you can give it a try:

```
$result = DB::table('table')
    ->select(DB::raw(
       "CONCAT(IF(Foreground > Background, Foreground, Background),',' ,IF(Foreground > Background, Background, Foreground)) as ColourCombination"
), DB::raw('COUNT(*) as ColourCombinationCount')) 
    ->groupBy('ColourCombination')
```

The idea is to concatenate the colours in alphabetical order to get a consistent value for every row with the same combination.

Then `$result` *should* have a value for every distinct colour combination along with the count.